# Unable to switch to frame while testing on IE but it is working fine with chrome

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am able to switch to frame and able to locate element in case of chrome but not able to locate in case of IE.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Logout')]")).submit();
```

using these two lines of code able to access but I think it is not switching in frame in case of IE.I tried switching frame by `WebElement`,index,name as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<frameset id="frRoot" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0" rows="125,26,*,0,0">
<frame id="frTopLeftPane" scrolling="no" name="brandingTop" src="/BIW/Lobby/Frameset/BrandingTop.aspx?dv=1&amp;nfGuid=">

<a style="vertical-align:top;" href="/ic/bin/logout.asp? 
sessionid=&amp;id=338206" target="_top">

<img src="/skins/BIW/NewSkin/images/logout.gif" alt=""> Logout
                    </a>
 </frame>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Error executing JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You should really upgrade your code, and should introduce **webDriverWait** for more stability. Try out the code given below :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("frRoot")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("frTopLeftPane")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Logout')]"))).submit();
```

Comment: It didn't work at all  giving error like INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such frame' (400 expected)

Comment: remove this line `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("frRoot")));` and try again

Comment: Thanks for your time everyone. Problem is resolved and only thing that I did is to change IE zoom level to 150% and code is working